# Get True/False text result from drop down selection

Tags: php, html, forms, menu, boolean

I'm trying to build a drop down menu with a list of city names. For city names where the return value is "true," I want text on the same page to be displayed saying the value is true. If the selection is where the return value is false, I want it to display this as well. I'm working with form actions and php trying to function it and have completely lost it. It's a simple task that I can not for the life of me figure out.

```
<select name="City">
<option value="Richmond">Richmond</option> //True//
<option value="Bowling Green">Bowling Green</option>//True
<option value="Manakin">Manakin</option>//false//
<option value="Emporia">Emporia</option>//false//
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['City'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val; "and this location is Not served" 
// Displaying Selected Value
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to write your own logic to do that. Why is Richmond `true` while Emporia is `false`? If you can answer it, you have the logic.

Comment: Handle this on server side or just show the  list of `true` cities only.

Comment: Create an array with the city names mapped to true/false: `$cities = ['Richmond' => true, ...];` and check against that using something like: `if ($cities[$_POST['City']]) { // true } else { // false }`.

Comment: Yes, I have the logic, but where I'm confused is how and where the logic is used to define the function. For example, Richmond is true because it's distance is true to service while Emporia is false because it's distance is false to service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an array which holds the state of the values, then you simply check the value which will determine the state.

```
<?php
$citys = [
    'Richmond' => true, 
    'Bowling Green' => true, 
    'Manakin' => false, 
    'Emporia' => false
];
?>

<select name="City">
<?php foreach ($citys as $city => $avail): ?>
    <option value="<?= $city ?>"><?= $city ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $selected_val = $_POST['City'] ?? '';  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

    if (isset($citys[$selected_val])) {
        echo "You have selected:".$selected_val." and this location is ".($citys[$selected_val] ? '' : 'Not').' served';
    } else {
        // error, city not in array
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, that worked. You saved me from bashing the keyboard. Thank you!

Comment: No worries glad to help.. using an array allows you later to abstract out the values into a db etc.